# How to correlate view order (using orderBy) with model order

Tags: angularjs, model, angularjs-filter, angularjs-orderby

I have an obviously simple but yet challenging problem in my AngularJS app:

When using `orderBy` on the view I loose the correlation between the order of the related model and the view order.

What I want to do: My view is a table. I want to set a highlight class for the selected row and I want to use cursor up/down keys to move this highlight.

I tried to decouple `$index` from the tracking by using `track by currentDocument.objectid`, but that doesn't seem to work.

How can I correlate the currently highlighted row in the view with the currently highlighted element of the related model in a way that I can use `-1` or `+1` with the cursor keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the order of the data is important to your business process, it makes sense to make the order part of your actual model. If you read the last example of `orderby` on the angular api (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy), you will notice they achieve this very thing. Basically, instead of binding `orderby` directly to some model value, create your own order function and manually order your model.

I have created a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/oM97ZTAIHTjI6YFiGDwI?p=preview Just click on the persons name to see the example (and reorder the list and try again).

Basically you create a manual sort function like this:

```
$scope.order = function(predicate, reverse) {
    $scope.friends = orderBy($scope.friends, predicate, reverse);
};
```

Which actually reorders the model itself, rather than just the view array. You can call it however you like. Then you can simply pass `$index` from the view, and it will correlate correctly to the view order.

Comment: In my case this seems to lead to an endless loop (reordering the model seems to trigger reodering in the view which seems to trigger reordering in the model etc etc). My model is populated dynamically so it doesn't exist in the beginning. That's why I used `orderBy:myorderfunction` in the view. Maybe I should call the custom sort filter only once every time I update the model .... will try

Comment: Yes that was it. I must not use `orderBy:` in the view any more instead I manually call the sort filter every time I update the model. Thank you!